# grep - recognize carriage return as new line

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to search a webserver running unix for php-files containing a specific string. Usually I use these commands to accomplish this:

find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H -i "the string to search for"

This has worked great so far, but now I've encountered a server where all the php-scripts don't have any line feeds, but instead only carriage returns. grep doesn't seem to recognize carriage return as new line, so the command above will print the entire contents of a file if there is a match within it, instead of just printing the line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). I'm going to close this copy; if you want the question here flag the [SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/317372/grep-recognize-carriage-return-as-new-line) version and ask them to migrate it

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient, but should work:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec bash -c "grep 'pattern' <(tr '\r' '\n' <{})" \;
```

This an alternative to show the file name:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec bash -c "grep 'pattern' <(tr '\r' '\n' <'{}') |
    sed s+^+'{}':\ +" \;
```

Comment: I really need the location of the file foreach match as well. Otherwise it was perfect.

Comment: @quano: here it is

Comment: wait, does this stop to search once it finds one match? That's what it seems like.

Comment: @quano: it should not